# Laravel - Error Call to undefined method App\Models\Roles::intersect()

Tags: php, laravel

I want to link a record of type `Person` to `Customer`, because I want to create a customer using the same record of type person, keeping both records the same but with different profiles, but I find the following problem in my code:

#### Error

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Roles::intersect()

##### `store()` method in `CustomerController.php`

```php
public function store(CustomerRequest $customerRequest)
{
    $role = Roles::where('name', 'Customer')->first();

    $customer = User::where('cpf', $customerRequest->cpf)->first();

    if ($customer->hasRole($role)) {
       return back()->with('msg_erro', "This user is already a customer profile.");
   } else {
       $customer->syncRoles([$role->id]);
   }
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where is the `intersect` function being called? Show us *that* code. Probably in `hasRole` or `syncRoles`, I presume.

Comment: @ceejayoz I guess that the problem are in ```hasRole()```. I put ```dd()``` inside of snippet ```if``` and don't return me your information.

Comment: Show your `hasRole` function, then?

Comment: You need to pull up `storage/logs/laravel.log` and inspect the actual stack trace to find where the error originates from, which is what's being asked for above. I assume it thinks there's a collection in play (`$this->intersect(...)` instead of `collect(...)->intersect(...)` or similar).

Comment: @JaredFarrish ```[2023-02-16 10:45:14] local.ERROR: Call to undefined method App\Models\Roles::intersect() {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Roles::intersect() at E:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel_project\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\ForwardsCalls.php:71)```

Comment: Put it in the question and include enough to see the last line reference that is code you wrote.